# I cannot search chat messages that are said by Will

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-search

When searching a room for chat messages, I have the option of searching the content of the message, as well as *who* said the message.

The feature is nifty in that the list will auto-complete for me when I type a few letters of their name in.

However, when I try to search for a particular statement that was made by [Will](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/wont), it won't present his name as a part of the auto-complete (which is actually necessary to use the feature at all.

There's no Will in the top part of the list:

[image: no Will in auto-complete part 1]

Or in the bottom:

[image: no Will in auto-complete part 2]

Granted, I can always put his user ID in the box, but that's *very* inconvenient.

And if you take away my ability to find Will's colorful contributions in chat, then you've taken away *any* satisfaction that I get from moderating (ok, maybe not, but it's a PITA regardless).

Comment: It Won't search for Will. Interesting...!

Comment: Looks to me like the drop-down list needs to be expandable. Even to search for "Robert Harvey", you have to enter practically his full name. The problem with "Will" is his name isn't long enough to get more specific!

Comment: @CodyGray It doesn't have to be long enough, but it *should* be in the list if I type just "Will", if I type more, then it should be dropped from the list.

Comment: By design.  No one cares what Will says.

Comment: @MatthewRead My first idea was to say "there are easier ways to delete your account," but... there probably actually aren't. I'll be sad to see you go, in any case. (Is what I _would_ say, if Will weren't so awesome.)